# Окончания зависимых слов

Tags: согласование

Здравствуйте. Помогите разобраться с одним вопросом.

Допустим, имеется предложение:
Ее ухо заполнили влага и жар.

Слово "заполнили" употреблено во множественном числе? Это правильно?
Например "Ее ухо заполнила влага и жар" звучит более естественно.

Часто возникают ситуации, когда к одному сказуемому относится сразу несколько подлежащих. Иногда подлежащие бывают разных родов и даже чисел. И если ставить сказуемое (не всегда глагол) во множественное число, то звучит как-то не так.

Найти соответствующий раздел правил не смог.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ее ухо **заполнили** влага и жар.

Обычно на выбор числа влияют несколько факторов, подробности можно посмотреть у Розенталя [§190. Согласование сказуемого с однородными подлежащими](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm)

"Сказуемое ставится в форме множественного числа, независимо от своего местоположения, если оно обозначает действие, совершаемое несколькими субъектами, например:  В душе его боролись желание забыть теперь о несчастном брате и сознание того, что это будет дурно (Л. Толстой)".